# INNER JOIN mysql return nothing

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to get the city name for my drop down list but using INNER JOIN and mysql but I end up getting no result, Please help me identify the issue. Thanks so much in advance.

```
SELECT city_name
from cities
INNER JOIN states
ON cities.city_id = states.state_id
GROUP BY cities.city_name
```

and here is my cities table database
[image]

and here is my states table databse
[image]

Comment: You are matching `city_id` and `state_id` - should they not both be `state_id`?

Comment: Oh....yes It works no wonder I get no results =( haha Thanks a lot @samiles really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your query should be:**

```
SELECT city_name
from cities
INNER JOIN states
ON cities.state_id = states.state_id
GROUP BY cities.city_name
```

You are matching `city_id` with `State_Id` which wouldn't fetch you anything